# trying to write Junit for repository interface with Predicate, criteria and specifications

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, junit, predicate

i tried to write junit for repository interface, but somehow it is having issues.

My interface:

```java
@Repository
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<SampleEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SampleEntity> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "SamplsHistory"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    public List<TestEntity> findAll(Specification<TestEntity> spec);
   
    public static Specification<SamplsEntity> fetchSamplssSpecification(SampleSearchCriteria criteria) {
        return (rootEntity, cq, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            
            **if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(criteria.getIds())) {
                In<Long> inId = cb.in(rootEntity.get(SamplConstants.Sampls_ID));
                criteria.getIds().forEach(inId::value);
                predicates.add(inId);
            }
            
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(criteria.getSearchText())) {
                Predicate apName= cb.like(rootEntity.get(SampleConstants.Sampls_NAME), "%" + criteria.getSearchText() + "%");
                predicates.add(cb.or(apName));
            }**
                            
            
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
```

and i tried written Junit for this but unable to do that>

My interface:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class SampleRepositoryTest {

    private Root<SampleEntity> root;
    private CriteriaQuery<?> cq;
    private CriteriaBuilder cb;

    @InjectMocks
    private SampleRepository SampleRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private SampleEntity SampleEntity;

    private static final String SEARCH_TERM_LIKE_PATTERN = "test%";

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this.getClass());
        SampleRepository = mock(SampleRepository.class);
        cb = mock(CriteriaBuilder.class);
        cq = mock(CriteriaQuery.class);
        root = (Root<SampleEntity>) Mockito.mock(Root.class);
    }

    @Test
    void fetchSamplesSpecification() {
        SampleSearchCriteria criteria = mock(SampleSearchCriteria.class);
        criteria.setSearchText("Marsh");

        Specification<SampleEntity> spec = (Specification<SampleEntity>) Mockito.mock(Specification.class);
        //when(SampleRepository.fetchSamplesSpecification(criteria)).thenReturn(spec);

        Predicate SampleNameIsLikePredicateMock = mock(Predicate.class);
        when(cb.like(root.get(AccountConstants.Sample_NAME), SEARCH_TERM_LIKE_PATTERN))
                .thenReturn(SampleNameIsLikePredicateMock);
        when(spec.toPredicate(root, cq, cb)).thenReturn(SampleNameIsLikePredicateMock);

        verify(root, times(1)).get(SampleConstants.Sample_NAME);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(root);
        // verify(cb, times(1)).like(root.get(SampleConstants.Sample_NAME),
        // SEARCH_TERM_LIKE_PATTERN);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(cb);

    }

    }   
}
```

Please check the above lets know is the junit is correct or not. Moreover when i tried the code coverage is not showing also junit is not successful.

Note : Need to cover the junit for repository.

Comment: There is nothing to inject into the `SampleRepository` nor will an instance be created. Also your test is testing absolutely nothing, it only tests the mocking framework nothing of your implementation.

Comment: Why do you have `SampleRepository = mock(SampleRepository.class);` when that's the class you want to test?

Comment: @tgdavies : this mock is useless... when i'm trying some approach i might have added while implementing this i have refered this : https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-data-jpa-examples/blob/master/tutorial-part-seven/src/test/java/net/petrikainulainen/spring/datajpa/repository/PersonSpecificationsTest.java

Comment: @M.Deinum : you mean this interface don't require junit or if the implementation is incorrect can you suggest me which what would be ideal solution for this to cover the code coverage ?

Comment: any help here ?